# Fantastic beasts

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Hint 1:

> Added tag "knowledge".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> [image]

Because:

> The images are of the following creatures from the Harry Potter / Fantastic Beasts world:  Murtlap, Occamy, Grindylow, Diricawl, Mooncalf, Graphorn, Hippogriff, Niffler, Centaur, Bowtruckle

And then:

> For each image, you count the number of creatures in the image, and take the nth letter from the name of the creature:
>  1 **m**urtlap, 4 occ**a**my, 1 **g**rindylow, 2 d**i**ricawl, 5 moon**c**alf, 2 g**r**aphorn, 1 **h**ippogriff, 2 n**i**ffler, 3 ce**n**taur, 2 b**o**wtruckle.
>
>  These letters spell out **magic rhino**.  This is a reference to the Erumpent, which is a magical rhino from Fantastic Beasts (pictured above).